# How to view GWT StackLayoutPanel without setting its Height in pixels

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I'm using GWT, I'm creating StackLayoutPanel dynamically. For eg. I have 4 or 5 StackLayoutPanels in a VerticalPanel. I set height of StackLayoutPanel in pixels. If i don't set the Height i see only one StackLayoutPanel in the view instead of 4 or 5. I want to see all the panels but don't want to set the Height in pixels.

My code,

```
    StackLayoutPanel stackLayoutPanel = new StackLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    stackLayoutPanel.setHeight("300px");
    List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList();
    VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    for(String value : list) {
         stackLayoutPanel.add(new Label("Hello"), new Label("Hai"), 4);
    }
    vPanel.add(stackLayoutPanel);
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Comment: Now you can see my code.

Comment: Does this help ? `stackLayoutPanel.setHeight("100%");`

Comment: No its not working. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if those css properties are changed, those panels will be get disappeared sometimes. So just try to edit those, I might be wrong if so forgive me. For the container of the stacked layout panels I think it would be nice to have a flex table.

Comment: Shamitha here I must use StackLayoutPanel. Since I need an accordion in the view.